# NSActivityindicator for a web browse

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

i want a circular activity indictor which should come when the web view start loading and should disappear when the load is complete

i have tried

```
-(void)WebViewDidStartLoad;(NSURL*)
 {
        [NSProgressIndicator startanimation:self];
 }
```

please help what should i type in .h and .m

Comment: What's that code? Is it really Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is add an UIActivityIndicatorView (this is the standard loading animation in iOS) in your storyboard / xib / viewController (anything you're using).

Then, in your .m file of your UIWebViewDelegate, you should do the following :

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Instantiate here your activity view if you're creating it programmatically
    // Then hide it, the user must not see it if web view is not loading
    self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = true;
    self.activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = true; // It will hide when animation is stopped
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    self.yourActivityIndicatorView.hidden = false;
    [self.yourActivityIndicatorView startAnimating]; 
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.yourActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating]; // It will hide automatically
}
```

In my case, i'm used to add it in a UIView, this way i can add a loading message (or anything else). When i start/stop the animation, i also show/hide the corresponding view.
Here you will find more information about [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidStartLoad%3a) and here about [UIActivityIndicatorView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html).